# Define root for PhoneGap (Build)

Tags: root, phonegap-build

Iv been searching for a clear answer to this for about 2 days now.  I have read and tested all the answers from similar questions without luck.  so I thought I would finally ask the good people of the community :)

Im using PhoneGap (Build) and have created a simple web app. The app needs to use multiple pages in multiple directories and I really want to avoid having to manually edit the references and links in different directories to make them relative e.g. ../../

I want to be able to reference resources and links from the root. e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">

<a href="/">Link back to homepage</a>
```

But this doesn't work? So my questions are:

1. What is the root of a phoneGap (build)? Bearing in mind the build version does not use a 'www' folder.
2. Is there any way I can use JS to define the root of my app?

Many thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: can you Show me your Phonegap Build Folder structure and index.html file ??

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. Any reason you need to do this? First of all - I have to say - You should **never** ever never ever make a Phonegap application that actually reloads separate html pages, if that is what you're doing. This will be an awful experience for your users and you'll face a high likelyhood of your app being rejected by Apple (if you want to submit to AppStore) as this means the screen will go *blank* between navigating pages. You really should look at building on a single-page architecture, using something like handlebars js. This way you will also be able to use cordovas onDeviceReady etc. properly, with multiple pages you will need to include all scripts in all pages..

See section 7 here: http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

SPA vs. MPA: http://java.dzone.com/articles/phonegap-architectural

Comment: Hey pppontusw, thanks for your advice.  Really? Will apple reject any multiple page app, that is not good news for me

Comment: I haven't seen any info warning against this in PG documentation.  

The app uses some complex JS for showing sequences of 3D animation frames and trying to combine these scripts along with everything else into 1 page would be a nightmare.  I don't agree that switching pages creates an awful user experience, if kept to a minimum its hardly noticeable.

Comment: I'm not saying they would routinely reject it, but this is something that detracts from the experience and they surely don't like that. Of course they want you to create native apps, but if you don't they require you to create a really good experience anyway. All I'm saying is read the link at: http://java.dzone.com/articles/phonegap-architectural because it will tell you what the risks are. If you are fine with it then that's OK but to answer the original question:  you need to reference them from the current path or the absolute path. Which is another part of why this makes it difficult.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks for your advice.  Im looking at using jQueryMobile to handle most of the pages, and then only changing actual page for these interactive 3D viewers.  Hopefully the experience will be good enough for them to overlook a couple of page changes.